Formatting LaTeX in Dash AG Grid headers and cells in Python
I'm trying to format my headers and cells to LaTeX/Markdown using the single $ inline notation. For example, a header might look like:
$\alpha$ = 0.5
While a cell might look like:
This is data: $\sigma$ = 2.71
I'm trying to use a Dash AG Grid in Python to display the grid in a Dash App while still formatting all the data the way it's meant to be displayed. I've tried several methods (e.g. Markdown cell renderer), but I keep falling short.
How do I display my headers and cells using inline LaTeX? Should I be doing something else?
I've already tried changing the columnDefs to
columnDefs=[{"field": col, 'cellRenderer': 'markdown'}
             for col in df.columns],

to try and see if Markdown formatting would do the trick, but it left the data formatted the exact same way it was before.

Instead of $\alpha$ = 0.5 you might want to use $\alpha = 0.5$ to get properc spacing around the equal sign.
